How to exploit new reduced 'covering radius' for integer linear programming
This paper apparently improves efficiency of looking for solutions to integer linear programming problems by reducing the needed 'covering radius' (see layman's explanation here). The constraints form a convex body K and the problem solutions are on an integer lattice L. From the original covering radius paper they state that the covering radius is "the least factor by which the body K needs to be blown up so that its translates by lattice vectors cover the whole space". I'm trying to understand how to apply this - how does the covering radius help matters, if I've got to search the convex body K entirely anyway ?
